# Java integer datatype

Tags: java

Could someone explain this text from Herbert Schildt.

> "The width of an integer type should not be thought of as the amount
>   of storage it  consumes, but rather as the behavior it defines for
>   variables and expressions of that type.  The Java run-time environment
>   is free to use whatever size it wants, as long as the types  behave as
>   you declared them."

Comment: Downvoters: please give the new guy some explanation as to why you think this is a bad question. I think it is an entirely reasonably thing to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is saying is that an `int` isn't necessarily implemented a 32-bit block of memory; it might be implemented, for example, as a 64-bit block of memory.

You don't really need to care about this, from the perspective of your code's behaviour: all you need know is that it behaves like a 32-bit block of memory, e.g. it can only store values between `-2^31` and `2^31 - 1`.

You *might* need to care about it if you are storing lots of ints: if it is storing them in 64 bits of memory each, you need twice as much memory as if they were stored in 32 bits. But this doesn't change the correctness of the code itself.